# How disable sql-maven-plugin file copy to temp folder?

Tags: java, maven, sql-maven-plugin

Here is a piece of plugin configuration:

```xml
<configuration>
    <srcFiles>
        <srcFile>src${file.separator}integration-test${file.separator}resources${file.separator}sql${file.separator}schema.sql</srcFile>
    </srcFiles>
</configuration>
```

Everything **works**, but I see in log:

```
[INFO] --- sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (create-tables) @ smsfinance-server ---
[INFO] Executing file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\schema.915861870sql
```

Is there a way to disable copying?

Comment: Why are those properties defined for the folder separator? You can simply write `<srcFile>src/integration-test/resources/..</srcFile>`...

Comment: Because Linux and Windows has different separators.

Comment: Is not neccessary. Simply use `/` that will work on Windows as well..

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible at the moment.

Reading [from the source code](https://github.com/mojohaus/sql-maven-plugin/blob/sql-maven-plugin-1.5/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/sql/SqlExecMojo.java#L766-L785) of version 1.5, the SQL Maven Plugin is copying the sources files to a temporary directory to handle filtering, even when filtering is disabled. Filtering is enabled with the attribute [`enableFiltering`](http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html#enableFiltering).

You could create an issue [at their GitHub page](https://github.com/mojohaus/sql-maven-plugin/issues) to disable copying of the file when filtering is disabled (which is the default).

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**

For cases when sql files is placed on ssd disk, you can specify tmp dir on ssd - just add `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/ssd-drive/tmp` to maven command line. It does **not** disable copying, **but** spead up sql execution process.